# Wait while screen rotates

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, ios-ui-automation

I wish to put a wait until the iPad screen is done rotating and want to have both rotate and wait in the same function. If I don't add few seconds of wait, then the app doesn't behave as expected. Below is the function:

```
LandScapeRight = function() 
{
   return UIATarget.localTarget().setDeviceOrientation(UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPERIGHT);
}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `delay()` method on `UIATarget`. The docs for the class are [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/UIATargetClass/UIATargetClass.html)

The quick and dirty way to do the delay you want is like so:

```
LandScapeRight = function() 
{
   var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
   target.setDeviceOrientation(UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPERIGHT);
   target.delay(1);   // Delay is in seconds, can be a fraction
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this two method

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```